# Is there a way to save "work sessions" in linux

Tags: linux, batch, session

I regularly work on different projects, using different software.

For project 1 I need to open for ex : Filezilla, Gedit and Nautilus (set to a specific folder)

For project 2 I need to open foz ex : Gimp, Nautilus (set to another specific folder)

etc.

What I would like is a kind of sessions manager, where I could create entries "project 1", "project 2", etc. And with one click or command, open all the softwares I need.

Perhaps there's an easy way to write a batch file for this? Any idea is welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to save multiple sessions per se, but you can write shell scripts that start multiple apps in the background.

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ cat > ~/bin/session1
#!/bin/sh
firefox &
gedit &
nautilus somedir &
<Ctrl-D>
$ chmod +x ~/bin/session1
$ session1
```

Creating a launcher on a panel is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, that's a start. The launcher, can do. Now I have to dig more into shell scripting :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try 'gnome-session' which will save the desktop session when you logout.
Then you could set up different user accounts for each project.